# How can I get the class by using class.forName("int[][][]")?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I have known that I can get the class of `int[]` by using `class.forName("[I")`, but How can I get the class of `int[][][]`?

Comment: Just do `int[][][].class` (and while you're at it, `int[].class`)?

Comment: @Sweeper: There are plenty of situations where that doesn't work, e.g. if you need to put the names in a config file and then use reflection to create instances etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `"[[[I"`. For any type `T`, an array class `T[]` has a name formed of `[` followed by the type name... even if `T` is already an array type.

More generally, you can find the name of a class in the same way I just did:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> clazz = int[][][].class;
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());
    }
}
```